# AD print group not working in some cases

Tags: network-printer, print-server, shared-printers

On our computer network there are many printers, and for some groups the task of connecting the closest printer has been sort of automated by creating a security group named print-
When we add computers to the group, the named printer is automatically connected. But on a few computers this does not work. I have checked naming, and AD container placement for the computer, but they are exactly the same as on the computers where this scheme works.

Any tips what to look for?

Comment: Did you reboot the computers in question? Changes to a computers group membership requires a reboot of the computer.

Comment: The computers have been rebooted repeatedly, but that did not help.

Comment: Check the event log PrintService\Operational.

Comment: I'd also suggest running the Group Policy Results wizard against one of the computers in question and taking a look at the resultant report.